# ajax post to jboss eap 7 without encodeURIComponent occurred messy code

Tags: javascript, ajax, tomcat, jboss, wildfly

Firstly,the project works well in tomcat(UTF-8) and jboss eap 6,the page encoding is also UTF-8.
Secondly,jboss config has add

`<servlet-container name="default" default-buffer-cache="default" stack-trace-on-error="local-only" default-encoding="UTF-8">`

Thirdly,when using encodeURIComponent or serialize it works well,however,it failed when using serialize and appending some parameters like follows:

```js
  var params = $("#form_viewOrUpdateSchedule").serialize();
  params += "&recordId=" + recordId;
  params += "&custName=" + custName;
  params += "&startTime=" + startTime;
  params += "&content=" + content;
  params += "&endTime=" + endTime;
  params += "&scheduleDate=" + getScheduleDate();
  bodymask();
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    data: params,
    datatype: "JSON",
 contentType : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
    success: function(data) {
```

Fourthly,it works well if using serialize or like follows:

```js
  var recordId = $("#schedule_list_id").val();
  var custName = $("#schedule_list_custName option:selected").val();
  var startTime = $("#schedule_list_startTime").val();
  var endTime = $("#schedule_list_endTime").val();
  var content = $("#schedule_list_content").val();
  var startIndex = $("#schedule_list_startTime").get(0).selectedIndex;
  var endIndex = $("#schedule_list_endTime").get(0).selectedIndex;
  if (startIndex > endIndex) {
    alertInfo("提示", "结束时间不能早于开始时间");
    return;
  }
  var params = {}
  params.recordId = recordId;
  params.custName = custName;
  params.startTime = startTime;
  params.content = content;
  params.endTime = endTime;
  params.scheduleDate = getScheduleDate();
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    data: params,
```

Fifthly,jboss eap 7(actually renamed to WildFly,version is 10) is based on undertow instead of tomcat.

Sixly,the similar question is asked in https://developer.jboss.org/thread/221662,and the problem that could not set default charactor encoding is solved in WildFly 8.0,mentioned in https://javaarm.com/faces/display.xhtml;jsessionid=bPtpE2lS35rYKscI0laAyYbp?tid=3341&page=1&print=true

Lastly,I wonder why it works well in tomcat with the above "thirdly" js and works failed in jboss eap 7 ? How to solve the problem if I don't change the js code ?

Comment: the project used a charactor filter to set charactor encoding to "UTF-8"

Comment: maybe like this: https://developer.jboss.org/message/970246#970246  .That metioned about that wildfly used jax-rs instead of servlet, so my encoding setting was inavailable. If so, why when I use encodeURIComponent it works well? That can't make sense.

Comment: Then the question is that tomcat could and jboss(wildFly) could not when post without encodeURIComponent or post data is not a js object. So why and how to solve it in wildFly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer why it worked well in tomcat but failed in WildFly by studying their source code.

In WildFly, you can see details in `io.undertow.server.handlers.form.FormEncodedDataDefinition.FormEncodedDataParser.doParse(final StreamSourceChannel channel)`,it handled like this:

```
buffer.clear();
int c = channel.read(buffer);
if (c > 0) {
       buffer.flip();
       while (buffer.hasRemaining()) {
       byte n = buffer.get();
       builder.append((char) n);//the problem occurred here,[a][b][c] would be changed to [0][a][0][b][0][c]
```

In tomcat,you can see details in `org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters.processParameters(byte bytes[], int start, int len,Charset charset)`

It uses `new String (byte[] bytes, int offset, int length, Charset charset)` to convert the post content from byte[] to String.

As a result, in this case, default encoding is utf-8, without js URIComponentEncoding, tomcat works well.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set uri encoding on http-listener (and any other)

for example:

```
<http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https" enable-http2="true" url-charset="UTF-8"/>
```

or cli:

```
/subsystem=undertow/server=default:server/http-listener=default:write-attribute(name="uri-charset", value="UTF-8")
```

and similarly for all other listeners you might be using.

Line of note, system properties named org.apache.catalina.* are tomcat related properties. Since WildFly 8+ and EAP7+ web server used is undertow and no longer jbossweb which was based on tomcat.
As such this properties won't have any effect at all.

Comment: Though I have added the line you mentioned,it doesn't work in my case.